# How to plot multiple asterisks for significance in ggplot facet plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet, p-value

I have created a facet plot in ggplot2 with multiple data sets presented in each figure as line charts. Some of the data points are significant according to a statistical test (p ≤ 0.05). I would like to indicate this on the plot with an asterisk above the data points that are significant.[I found this example of having asterisks displayed above the significant values](http://www.mdpi.com/marinedrugs/marinedrugs-11-02398/article_deploy/html/images/marinedrugs-11-02398-g002-1024.png)

The color of the asterisk should correspond to the color of the data set used in the plot. And when there are multiple significant data sets for that point on the x-axis then the asterisks should be stacked vertically so they do not obscure each other by overlapping.

In my input data I have an additional column with the p-value. Could anyone point me towards the way to do this ggplot2 (if it is possible at all) or help me with the code.

My current plot (legend is cropped off the right hand side to make the rest of the figure larger here):

[image]

My current code:

```
ggplot(MyData,aes( x = DAF, y = Mvalue ,group=Species, colour = Species)) + geom_line(size=1.3) + xlab("Frequencies") + ylab("Score")  + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0, size = 6)) + theme(axis.text.y=element_text( size = 6)) + facet_wrap(~Variant) + geom_point()
```

Example of input data for 2 of the 9 datasets (the rest would continue below). For this data the asterisks for significance (p ≤ 0.05) would be for lines 6,7,8,10,14 & 19 based on the value in the final column being ≤ 0.05 :

```
1   Species Variant DAF Mvalue  pvalue
2   Tom 5' UTR  0.1-0.19    -1.6026346186   NA
3   Tom 5' UTR  0.2-0.29    1.1646939405    NA
4   Tom 5' UTR  0.3-0.39    0.0003859956    9.84E-01
5   Tom 5' UTR  0.4-0.49    0.0226744644    3.28E-01
6   Tom 5' UTR  0.5-0.59    0.1163627387    3.22E-05
7   Tom 5' UTR  0.6-0.69    0.1614562558    6.33E-06
8   Tom 5' UTR  0.7-0.79    0.221583632 4.29E-06
9   Tom 5' UTR  0.8-0.89    0.1231280752    1.42E-01
10  Tom 5' UTR  0.9-0.99    0.5765076152    9.13E-03
11  Tom 5' UTR  1   5.8105310419    1.87E-13
12  Jerry   5' UTR  0.1-0.19    -0.1371122871   NA
13  Jerry   5' UTR  0.2-0.29    -0.0539638465   4.30E-01
14  Jerry   5' UTR  0.3-0.39    0.1666681074    1.45E-02
15  Jerry   5' UTR  0.4-0.49    0.0081950639    9.19E-01
16  Jerry   5' UTR  0.5-0.59    -0.1204254909   1.82E-01
17  Jerry   5' UTR  0.6-0.69    0.1017622151    3.15E-01
18  Jerry   5' UTR  0.7-0.79    0.1293398031    3.16E-01
19  Jerry   5' UTR  0.8-0.89    0.2944195851    4.52E-02
20  Jerry   5' UTR  0.9-0.99    -0.2956980914   2.12E-01
21  Jerry   5' UTR  1   0.0746902715    7.63E-01
```

If it is much simpler I could replace the p-value column with a 0 or a 1 indicating if the value is significant.

I tried to show my previous work and some example input data. Let me know if I can improve my question. 
Thank you for your suggestions.

Here is a dput() output of a subset of the data as requested:

```
structure(list(Species = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Jerry", 
"Tom"), class = "factor"), Variant = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("3' UTR", 
"5' UTR", "Missense", "Stop gained"), class = "factor"), DAF = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("0.1-0.19", "0.2-0.29", "0.3-0.39", 
"0.4-0.49", "0.5-0.59", "0.6-0.69", "0.7-0.79", "0.8-0.89", "0.9-0.99", 
"1"), class = "factor"), Mvalue = c(-1.6026346186, 1.1646939405, 
0.0003859956, 0.0226744644, 0.1163627387, 0.1614562558, 0.221583632, 
0.1231280752, 0.5765076152, 5.8105310419, -0.0251257018, -0.022586792, 
0.0089090304, 0.037280128, 0.0745842692, 0.0831538898, 0.0762765259, 
0.1750634419, 0.2095647328, NA, -0.0139837967, -0.0218524964, 
-0.023889027, -0.0042744306, 0.0949525873, 0.087866945, 0.1379730494, 
0.2719542633, 0.4726727792, NA, 0.0201430038, 0.1304518218, -0.0948886785, 
-0.2329137983, -0.0901357588, 0.0504128137, -0.2308377878, 0.4422620731, 
NA, NA, -0.1371122871, -0.0539638465, 0.1666681074, 0.0081950639, 
-0.1204254909, 0.1017622151, 0.1293398031, 0.2944195851, -0.2956980914, 
0.0746902715, -0.005168038, 0.0403712226, -0.0034692714, -0.0049252304, 
-0.0089669044, -0.0604522846, 0.1061225099, 0.0180975445, -0.1843156999, 
-0.1920104157, 0.2228406046, 0.0532141252, 0.0670815638, -0.1197784096, 
-0.235101482, -0.1920644059, -0.2493575855, -0.1564613691, -0.2600385981, 
0.069079018, 0.0503810571, 0.4346052688, 0.1300533982, 0.0662828745, 
-0.4627398332, -1.081459609, -0.7693678877, -0.4865007276, -0.0230373639, 
0.4693415234), pvalue = c(NA, NA, 0.984, 0.328, 3.22e-05, 6.33e-06, 
4.29e-06, 0.142, 0.00913, 1.87e-13, NA, NA, 0.354, NA, 1.93e-07, 
7.29e-06, 0.00288, 2.48e-05, 0.1, 0.791, 0.124, NA, 0.131, 0.824, 
4.11e-05, 0.00354, 0.000711, 3.1e-05, 0.0122, 0.871, 0.73, 0.0963, 
0.367, NA, 0.574, 0.799, 0.442, 0.267, 0.319, 0.98, NA, 0.43, 
0.0145, 0.919, 0.182, 0.315, 0.316, 0.0452, 0.212, 0.763, 0.824, 
0.096, 0.896, 0.868, 0.779, 0.124, 0.0261, 0.761, NA, NA, 6.44e-22, 
0.0407, 0.0162, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.481, 0.809, 0.0236, 
0.573, 0.801, 0.172, NA, 0.186, 0.449, 0.975, 0.513)), .Names = c("Species", 
"Variant", "DAF", "Mvalue", "pvalue"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

Comment: Can you use `dput()` in R, so we can easily use your data without manipulation?

Comment: I think that if you find a way to do that, the graph would be really hard to read actually. I suggest to add a `scale` on the type of point (circle = Not significant, Diamond = Significant) for instance. you can play also on the size of the point.

Comment: The scale is a great idea. Is there a way to do filled circles for significant, unfilled for significant? Though I worry the overlapping lines might still obscure these points. But I could play with size like you said. How should I use dput(), it gives me a very long list of values and I didn't want to post all the data here as there are > 600 rows.

Comment: i created a file of input data with dput() what is the correct way to share it here?

Comment: Just add it to your post. If it's really big consider providing only relevant subset.

Comment: I added as much of the data as I could before hitting the wordlimit. It very large and begins with structure section with values like '454L, 444L', then a label section with the actual data, which looks like the data I provided above but comma seperated and with "" for each row. I wasn't sure how to subset the corresponding subset and label sections so maybe that is problematic.

Comment: Subset it before using dput(). It shouldn't end with a comma. You could filter to only provide 2 Variants (variable used in facet_wrap) instead of 9 like in your plot.

Comment: Done. I should have thought of that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. It works with 2 Species as in your example, but should work with more species.

```
library(data.table)
MyData <- data.table(MyData)
MyData$signif <- ifelse(MyData$pvalue < 0.05,1,0)
```

To determine when there is more than 1 significative value on the same point

```
MyData[, temp:=cumsum(signif), by=c("Variant", "DAF")]
```

The loop create the asterisk "y value", based on the point "y value" + 0.5.
When there is a n  significative point, it increment the nth point "y value" by n*0.5.

```
for (i in 1:length(levels(MyData$Species))) {
  MyData[temp == i , y_ast:=max(Mvalue, na.rm=TRUE)+(i*0.5), by=c("DAF", "Variant")]
}


ggplot(MyData,aes( x = DAF, y = Mvalue ,group=Species, colour = Species)) +
  geom_line(size=1) + xlab("Frequencies") + ylab("Score")  +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0, size = 6)) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text( size = 6)) +
  facet_wrap(~Variant) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_point(data = MyData[MyData$signif ==1, ],aes(x=DAF, y=y_ast),shape = "*", size=8, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

If you want to show the asterisks on the trend as I suggest, just replace `y=y_ast` by y=`Mvalue` in the last line.

PS: I use `data.table` as I'm used to, but `y_ast` value can be calculate using the R `base` package or `dplyr` for instance

Answer (score 2):

One way that could work:
The dataset containing the position of the asterisks, that is the points for which p-value is significant

```
library(dplyr)
df_asterisk=MyData%>%
  filter(pvalue<0.05)
```

Another dataframe that contains values for which more than 1 p-value is significant. A new column `id` is added to differenciate the different group.

```
Id_group=df_asterisk%>%
  group_by(Variant,DAF)%>%
  filter(n()>1)%>%
  mutate(id=data.table::rleid(Mvalue))
```

Mvalue is used for the position of the *, we change it in the dataframe used for the mapping. I used the value of the column `id` created previously to differentiate the asterisk (no overlapping). A simpler approach could be to ignore this step and add a random component to the mapping (and redraw if not satisfactory).

```
df_asterisk[with(df_asterisk, duplicated(interaction(Variant, DAF))|duplicated(interaction(Variant, DAF), fromLast = T)),]$Mvalue<-(df_asterisk[with(df_asterisk, duplicated(interaction(Variant, DAF))|duplicated(interaction(Variant, DAF), fromLast = T)),]$Mvalue) + Id_group$id/4
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(MyData,aes( x = DAF, y = Mvalue ,group=Species, colour = Species)) +
  geom_line(size=1.3) +
  xlab("Frequencies") +
  ylab("Score")  +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0, size = 6)) +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text( size = 6)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(data=df_asterisk,aes(x=DAF,y=Mvalue),label="*",size=5,nudge_y=1)+
  facet_wrap(~Variant)
```

I change a datapoint to have 2 signifcant p-values in DAF for 5' to see how it looked.
[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I will look through this answer and make sure I understand it, this is very helpful